# linux sort 'field skip' options not documented, but seem to work

Tags: linux, sort

I was porting over a script from AIX to linux that had code of the form

```
grep <pattern> $LOG | sort -b +rn4 -5 +2 -3
```

On AIX, this kind of sort syntax is documented, and basically the +a -b syntax means skip a fields and consider fields between a and b as your sort key.

This didn't work on linux, because the linux sort command didn't like including the 'rn' (reverse numeric) flags in the +a 'skip fields' parameter.  but this did work:

```
grep <pattern? $LOG | sort -b -rn +4 -5 +2 -3
```

So apparently the 'field skipping logic *is* supported by linux sort, but not documented in the man page (that I could see, anyway).  the -k option works on both systems to specify a key field number.  But here's a weird quirk.  On AIX

```
ls -l | sort -n +4
```

produces a list of files sorted on the 5th field (size).  But on linux, the same command produces an error:

sort: cannot read: +4: No such file or directory

```
ls -l | sort -n +4 -5
```

does work, though.  So, apparently the + skip - skip key-selection syntax sort of works, but only if you specify both the starting and ending column skip parameters.  And it's not documented.  So, my question - is this column skipping syntax deprecated?  Does it just work because the code was just there in the command and nobody knew to take it out?

Answer (score 8):

I’m assuming your Linux system uses GNU `sort`; GNU `sort`’s man page doesn’t provide complete documentation. Instead, the documentation is provided as an Info file (`info sort`) and is [also available in the online Coreutils manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html). The latter describes the behaviour you’re seeing:

> On systems not conforming to POSIX 1003.1-2001, `sort` supports a traditional origin-zero syntax ‘`+pos1 [-pos2]`’ for specifying sort keys. The traditional command ‘`sort +a.x -b.y`’ is equivalent to ‘`sort -k a+1.x+1,b`’ if *y* is ‘`0`’ or absent, otherwise it is equivalent to ‘`sort -k a+1.x+1,b+1.y`’.
>
> This traditional behavior can be controlled with the `_POSIX2_VERSION` environment variable (see [Standards conformance](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Standards-conformance.html#Standards-conformance)); it can also be enabled when `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is not set by using the traditional syntax with ‘*`-pos2`*’ present.

If you run GNU `sort` with `_POSIX2_VERSION` set to `199209` in its environment, you’ll be able to use `+x` on its own:

```
ls -l | _POSIX2_VERSION=199209 sort -n +4
```